Exploring Solutions for Enhanced Data Storage in Ethereum Wallets
Vitalik recently raised an important point about the need for robust data storage solutions in crypto wallets https://vitalik.eth.limo/general/2024/12/03/wallets.html. Chris Were, the CEO and co-founder of Verida, shared a thought-provoking tweet addressing this issue: https://x.com/tahpot/status/1865921233365487654.
Verida is actively working on decentralized data and wallet innovations, making Chris's perspective especially relevant. As someone interested in advancing wallet technology, I’d like to explore:

What are the technical limitations of current wallet data storage systems?
Are there existing projects or frameworks that align with Vitalik's vision for improved data handling in wallets?
How could decentralized protocols (like those Verida works on) be integrated into Ethereum wallets to address these challenges?

I’d love to hear from the community about potential solutions, best practices, or ongoing projects tackling this issue.
